# design pattern for dynamic buttons in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So looking to write an application that will throw up a large number of buttons on the screen, the number of buttons and to some degree their functions will all be based on the users preference. The buttons functions will be dependent on setting, the look will be themed, the only set thing is that the buttons will be in a grid from `2x2` to `6x9`.

My question is, anyone have any suggestions on design patterns. Was thinking I would just render them one by one naming them `[alpha row][column number]`, so the buttons will be

```
A1    A2     A3 
B1    B2     B3
```

Potentially using two ng-repeat loops. But thinking there might be some smoother solution?

Comment: What does the name of the button have to do with its position?

Comment: Its the tie back to code. So I want to be able to connect each button to a function, and as the function will be dependent on configuration, I need a way of identifying it for the code.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. Maybe you could setup an example of some kind?